# operator overloading of plus sign in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand operator overloading of plus sign. I see 2 prototypes:

```
Box operator+(const Box& b) { ... }
Box operator+(const Box& left, const Box& right) { ... }
```

Which one is right? If the difference is only that first is member function and second is non-member, then lets say I define both ways, then which one will be called on ?

```
Box a, b;
Box c = a + b;
```

Comment: Try it. (fill, fill)

Comment: _"lets say I define both ways"_ What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @RustyX: I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is "right" or "better" depends on your application. The member version gives access to all private attributes and methods of `Box`, the non-member version doesn't unless it's declared as a `friend` of `Box`. But a non-member can be templated and made to apply to a wide range of types.

Members are not preferred by the compiler over non-members in general, nor vice versa. Instead C++ [overload resolution rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) are applied to select one or the other.

`Box Box::operator+(const Box& b)` is treated as though it takes two arguments: `Box&` which refers to the object used to call the member function (`*this`), and `const Box& b`.

In your example, both `a` and `b` are non-const.

In order to call `Box Box::operator+(const Box& b)`, `b` needs to be converted to a const reference.

In order to call `Box operator+(const Box& left, const Box& right)`, both `a` and `b` need to be converted to const references.

So the member operator is selected because it is a better match (requires less conversions).

Had your member `operator+` been declared `const`, you would have gotten a compiler error because the call would become ambiguous.

Comment: One other important difference: a non-member allows implicit conversions of the left hand operand to `Box`; a member does not.